# How to link CoreMotion framework in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks, core-motion

I'm having trouble installing a framework in XCode(CoreMotion).

I think it supposed to come along with XCode, but when I look for it in the existing frameworks it doesn't appear.

Does this library come with XCode 4(which I can't get because I need an OS update)?

<s>Is it possible to install it from scratch?</s>(figured that out)

Where can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have it with xcode.

Click on your project -> click on your target -> click build phases -> link binary with libraries -> + sign at bottom of table then search for it and add it.

Sometimes the folder folds up when you're searching for it, so make sure its in expanded state.

Comment: OK, Thanks! I just figured out that CoreMotion does not work with simulator 3.2, it only works with 4.0 and above.